# How to remove value from route int .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I'm writing .net core mvc app. I have two methods

```
    [HttpGet("{action}/{userId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeUser(string userId)
    {
        var user = await _dbContext.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        ...
        return View(new ChangeUserVM());
    }

    [HttpPost("{action}/{userId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeUser(ChangeUserVM user)
    {
        ...
    }
```

I need routing in the `HttpGet` method to get into the first method. But then i want to get from the html to the second method and i have to use routing again otherwise i get 405. How i can get rid of routing in the second method?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. The route can have corresponding placeholders to be bound with your model, if you don't want some value, just remove the corresponding placeholders from that route. BTW please be more specific about an issue, a concrete example (e.g: what the exact info you want to get rid of ...) should be better. We don't talk generally in SO unless it's fairly well-known or comes with a specific example.

Comment: Now i use in the second method [HTTPPost("{action}/{userId}")], but i want to use simply [HTTPPost]

Comment: How do you want to access the Post method?

Comment: @kirillbasic basically you want the framework to understand something you don't want to say or tell it. So how can it know what you want? that does not make sense at all. If you mean you don't want to use `attribute routing` (one way to direct the routing) then you have another way to tell it what you want by using `conventional routing`. That's the last thing you must use if you don't want to use `attribute routing`.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t verify my suggestion right now, but over second method, try to remove from HttpPost attribute “userId”.

```
[HttpPost(“action”)]
public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeUser(ChangeUserVM user)
```

Comment: i tried to do this, but if i do so i get 405